.Net MAUI Content View and Bindable Properties
I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong while creating a custom .NET MAUI control using ContentView. I have read through the docs many times but I still can't get it to behave as I would expect it to. It is possible that I am expecting the wrong outcome. I am writing this control entirely in C# without XAML and I am using the CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup package to bind to the component. The custom control is defined like so:
public partial class Elevation : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
           nameof(TapCommand),
           typeof(ICommand),
           typeof(Elevation),
           default(ICommand));

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(TapCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(TapCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(CornerRadius),
        typeof(CornerRadius),
        typeof(Elevation),
        new CornerRadius(5));

    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }

    new public static readonly BindableProperty ShadowProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Shadow),
        typeof(Shadow),
        typeof(Elevation),
        new Shadow());

    new public Shadow Shadow
    {
        get => (Shadow)GetValue(ShadowProperty);
        set => SetValue(ShadowProperty, value);
    }

    public Elevation()
    {
        Content = new Border()
        {
            Content = Content
        }.Bind(PaddingProperty, nameof(Padding), source: this)
         .Bind(BackgroundColorProperty, nameof(BackgroundColor), source: this)
         .Bind(ShadowProperty, nameof(Shadow), source: this)
         .Bind(Border.StrokeShapeProperty, nameof(CornerRadius), source: this, converter: new CornerRadiusToRoundRectangleConverter());
    }
}

public class CornerRadiusToRoundRectangleConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is CornerRadius cornerRadius)
        {
            return new RoundRectangle { CornerRadius = cornerRadius };
        }
        return new RoundRectangle { CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5) };
    }

    public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

And this is how I would expect to use it based on what I have read/learned so far:
new Elevation()
        {
            Padding = 10,
            CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5, 30, 5, 30),
            TapCommand = new Command(new Action(() => {})),
            Content = new Grid()
            {
                Children =
                {
                new Grid()
                {
                    ColumnDefinitions = Columns.Define(25, Star, Star),
                    Children =
                    {
                        new Label()
                            .Text("Hello")
                            .Font(size: 18)
                            .Column(1),
                        new MauiIcon()
                            .End()
                            .CenterVertical()
                            .Icon(FontAwesomeSolidIcons.ChevronRight)
                            .IconSize(12.5)
                            .Column(2)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.AppThemeColorBinding(
            BackgroundColorProperty,
            Colors.Black,
            Colors.White);

The Padding and BackgroundColor properties are being applied properly and are visible in the UI but the Shadow and StrokeShape properties are not reflected in the UI. I am also not confident that I am using the Content property correctly. Any thoughts here as I am out of ideas?

May I know how do you consume the ContentView and how do you set the BindingContext for the ContentView?

If I am specifying the source parameter in each binding, I would think I don't need to explicitly set the binding context. Is that not true?

Since you use the Border control as the Content of the Elevation, my advice is to let the Elevation implement Border. Then you don't have to create some BindableProperty such as Shadow as Border has already owned them. Also, I will just define the Content in Elevation,
public partial class Elevation : Border
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
           nameof(TapCommand),
           typeof(ICommand),
           typeof(Elevation),
           default(ICommand));

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(TapCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(TapCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public Elevation()
    {

        Content = new Grid()
        {
            Children =
                {
                    new Grid()
                    {
                        ColumnDefinitions = Columns.Define(25, Star, Star),
                        Children =
                        {
                            new Label()
                                .Text("Hello")
                                .Font(size: 18)
                                .Column(1),
                            new MauiIcon()
                                .End()
                                .CenterVertical()
                                .Icon(FontAwesomeSolidIcons.ChevronRight)
                                .IconSize(12.5)
                                .Column(2)
                            }
                        }
                    }
        };
    }
}

And when you want to consume it, just use the code like
Elevation e = new Elevation()
{
    Padding = 10,      
    TapCommand = new Command(new Action(() => { })),
    StrokeShape = new RoundRectangle() { CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5,30,5,30)}

};

Of course, you don't need a Converter any more.
For more info, you may refer to Border. Please let me know if you have any question.

thats a great idea. that wiuld greatly simplify things. i will try that. thanks!

Don't mention it. Alternately  you could create the Elevation  and then just put it in a Border when creating the UI.
